# how do i make a sound to be heard multiple times?

Tags: javascript, html

i did a code that let me press a button and hear a voice. the problem is that untill that voice ends i cant repeat that voice and i need to let it finish before pressing the button again. how do i make it possible to play the voice multiple times without waiting for it to finish playing?

the code is -

```
<audio id="bass">
<source src="bass.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
<article id="cont">

var bass = document.getElementById('bass');

document.addEventListener('keydown',function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 90) {
        bass.play();
    }
});
```

Comment: how are you loading the audio into `bass`?

Comment: you want a multithread cycle then that will concurently make beep sound?

Comment: i added the voice so you can see it hope itll help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `load()` before `play()` it should work.

`load` reloads the audio so it's like resetting the audio.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown',function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 90) {
        bass.load();
        bass.play();
    }
});
```

[Demo with another file](http://jsfiddle.net/r4ed5/)

Answer (score 0):

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/3jWX8/)

**HTML**

```
<embed src="success.wav" autostart="false" width="0" height="0" id="sound1" enablejavascript="true">
```

**JS**

```
document.addEventListener('keydown',function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 90) {
        var sound = document.getElementById('sound1');
        sound.Play();
    }
});
```

Note: this is just a quick guess, it fixed some syntax errors and hopefully helps you.  If not let me know.

Comment: It should be `sound1` instead of `soundObj` and also you should enclose it in quotes `(")` `document.getElementById("sound1");`.

Comment: @VedantTerkar good call, it is untested so I appreciate the assist.

Comment: @VedantTerkar according to http://www.strout.net/info/dvorak/original.pke it is the 'J' key.  my jsFiddle doesn't work because i didn't include the wav file or a url to a real file.